# Defining constants for a number of scripts and modules in perl

Tags: perl, coding-style, constants

I am facing the following problem:
I am working on a perl project consisting of a number of modules and scripts. The project must run on two different machines.

Throughout the project i call external programs, but the paths are different on both machines, so I would like to define them once globally for all files and then only change this definition when i switch machines.

Since I am fairly new to perl I ask you what would be a common way to accomplish this.
Should I use "use define" or global variables or something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pardon me for this perhaps silly question, but if you know you're going to need local definitions on variables, why use globals at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a module to hold your configuration information.

In file `My/Config.pm` in your perl library path:

```
package My::Config;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp ();

my %setup = (
   one => {path => '/some/path'},
   two => {path => '/other/path'},
);

my $config = $setup{ $ENV{MYCONFIG} }
     or Carp::croak "environment variable MYCONFIG must be set to one of: "
              .(join ' ' => keys %setup)."\n";

sub AUTOLOAD {
    my ($key) = our $AUTOLOAD =~ /([^:]+)$/;
    exists $$config{$key} or Carp::croak "no config for '$key'";
    $$config{$key}
}
```

And then in your files:

```
use My::Config;

my $path = My::Config->path;
```

And of course on your machines, set the environment variable `MYCONFIG` to one of the keys in `%setup`.

Comment: thank you, I did it like this, although I know there is multiple ways of doing it.... guess that's perl... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd definitely do my best to avoid global variables - they are a sign of weak coding style (in any language) and offer you a maintenance hell.

Instead, you could create and use configuration files - one for each of your machines. Being on Perl, you have plenty of options for free, ready to use CPAN modules:

- [Config::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Config-Auto-0.38/lib/Config/Auto.pm)
- [Config::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~rizen/Config-JSON-1.5100/lib/Config/JSON.pm)
- [Config::YAML](http://search.cpan.org/~meettya/Config-YAML-Modern-0.36/lib/Config/YAML/Modern.pm)

And many many other

Comment: That would mean I would have to load this file in every function that uses these variables right?
That seems a little heavy to me...

Comment: you would have to load the package that defines the global vars anyways, or at least define them in every package. You could use only one global variable - the one that holds your config object and get your static values through that.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than defining globals which may or may not work, why not use a subroutine to find a working executable?

```
my $program = program_finder();
sub program_finder {
    -x && return $_ for qw( /bin/perl /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/perl );
    die "Could not find a perl executable";
}
```